# Python-RPM show different result between Python 3 and Python 2

Tags: python

I am transfering a script from Python 2 to Python 3.

I am using the following code to check an RPM package.

```
import rpm
TS=rpm.TransactionSet()
CHECKPACKAGE=TS.dbMatch('name', 'gpm')
for h in CHECKPACKAGE:
    print("%s-%s-%s" % (h['name'], h['version'], h['release']))

if (h['version'] == "1.20.7") and (h['release'] == "7.60"):
   print("=> check gpm: version gpm is in sync")
   print("")
else:
   print("!!!check gpm: version gpm is NOT in sync please check!!!")
   print("")
```

With Python 2 I got

```
gpm-1.20.7-7.60
=> check gpm: version gpm is in sync
```

With Python 3 I got

```
b'gpm'-b'1.20.7'-b'7.60'
!!!check gpm: version gpm is NOT in sync please check!!!
```

What can I do to have the same result with Python3?

Regards

Comment: Why do you print all of the `h`'s in `CHECKPACKAGE`, but only validate the last one?

Comment: This is only example code to show my problem. The real code is a bit longer with more checks.

Comment: @ChrisJ Do you mind me asking where you got the rpm module compatible with Python 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call method `decode()` on `h['release']` and `h['version']`:

```
if (h['version'].decode() == "1.20.7") and (h['release'].decode() == "7.60"):
...
```

It looks like you have a byte string instead of a string.

You can understand it comparing `gpm-1.20.7-7.60` and `b'gpm'-b'1.20.7'-b'7.60'`.

`decode()` will remove `b''`.

Comment: Thx Daria. This is the solution. I have to wait 6 min to mark your answer as solution.